# How to add parameter through array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding a parameter through `Querystring`.
My code is:

```
 SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Showvillage", Constr1);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Yojna_No", Request.QueryString[0]);
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Village_Code", Request.QueryString[1]);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Now due to my requirement i have to send multiple value for each parameter and the multiple value is coming as `Session` array from previous page.Can anyone solve how to add that session array to parameter

```
 SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Showvillage", Constr1);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string[] getyojna = (string[])Session["value"];
        string[] getvillage = (string[])Session["values"];
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Yojna_No", Request.QueryString[0]);//change here for session
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Village_Code", Request.QueryString[1]);//change here for session
```

Comment: Check this link hope it will work. > **http://forums.asp.net/t/1538079.aspx/1**

Answer (score 2):

```
 SqlParameter something = new SqlParameter("parameterName", "value");
     SqlParameter something2 = new SqlParameter("parameterName2", "value2");
    SqlParameterCollection parameters=new SqlParameterCollection();
    parameters.Add(something);
    parameters.Add(something2);
```

Maybe you should use something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have successully assigned the session object `Session["values"]` to `getvillage` string array then you can simply use index of string array (getvillage) to get elements.

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Yojna_No", getvillage[0]);
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Village_Code", getvillage[1]);
```

Comment: what if i need to send multiple value. So i have to use for loop again.

Comment: 'int count = vill.Rows.Count;
string[] ar = new string[count];  for (int i = 0; i < vill.Rows.Count; i++)
                {  string yojna=vill.Rows[i]["YojnaNo"].ToString();   ar[i] = yojna;}
                Session["value"] = ar;' this is my code to add array in session can u check it too

Comment: Where you have this loop ? as I could not see in question